# Use GeoTools to read WaterML files

Tags: geotools, gml

I want to read [WaterML 2.0](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/waterml) time series. I am totally new to WaterML but I read it rely on `GML 3.2`. It would be great to use GeoTools to do that, maybe extending the `GML` classes. Is there some docs or examples about extending GeoTools `GML`? Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Probably want to look at [GMLAS - Geography Markup Language (GML) driven by application schemas](http://www.gdal.org/drv_gmlas.html) this is used by the [GML Application Schema toolbox QGIS plugin](https://github.com/BRGM/gml_application_schema_toolbox) in QGIS 3 (2.99)